# Do events returning to the top of the sub?

Tags: vba

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim webstring As String
    Dim webarray() As String
    If first_time = True Then
        Dim randomValue1 As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor((2 - 1 + 1) * Rnd())) + 1
        Dim randomValue2 As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor((4 - 3 + 1) * Rnd())) + 3
        Dim randomValue3 As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor((6 - 5 + 1) * Rnd())) + 5
        Dim randomValue4 As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor((8 - 7 + 1) * Rnd())) + 7
        Dim randomValue5 As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor((10 - 9 + 1) * Rnd())) + 9
        Dim randomValue6 As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor((10 - 1 + 1) * Rnd())) + 1
        If randomValue6 = randomValue1 Or randomValue6 = randomValue2 Or randomValue6 = randomValue3 Or randomValue6 = randomValue4 Or randomValue6 = randomValue5 Then
            randomValue6 = CInt(Math.Floor((10 - 1 + 1) * Rnd())) + 1
        End If

        wb.Navigate(New Uri("http://direct.notaurl.org/games/index.php?sub=29&id=11393&ticket=" & randomValue6))
        Do Until wb.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
        wb.Navigate(New Uri("http://direct.notaurl.org/games/index.php?sub=57"))
        Do Until wb.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop

        webstring = wb.DocumentText.ToString()
        webarray = Split(webstring, ";")
        item_id = webarray(0)

        wb.Navigate("http://notaurl.org/games/index.php?sub=32&id=" & item_id & "&ticket=" & randomValue1)
        Do Until wb.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
        wb.Navigate("http://notaurl.org/games/index.php?sub=32&id=" & item_id & "&ticket=" & randomValue2)
        Do Until wb.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
        wb.Navigate("http://notaurl.org/games/index.php?sub=32&id=" & item_id & "&ticket=" & randomValue3)
        Do Until wb.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
        wb.Navigate("http://notaurl.org/games/index.php?sub=32&id=" & item_id & "&ticket=" & randomValue4)
        Do Until wb.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
        wb.Navigate("http://notaurl.org/games/index.php?sub=32&id=" & item_id & "&ticket=" & randomValue5)
        Do Until wb.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
        first_time = False
    End If

    wb.Navigate("http://notaurl.org/games/index.php?sub=57&fieldid=" & item_id)
    Do Until wb.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop

    webstring = wb.DocumentText.ToString()
    webarray = Split(webstring, ";")
    If webarray(0) = "WIN" Then
        Dim randomValue1 As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor((2 - 1 + 1) * Rnd())) + 1
        Dim randomValue2 As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor((4 - 3 + 1) * Rnd())) + 3
        Dim randomValue3 As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor((6 - 5 + 1) * Rnd())) + 5
        Dim randomValue4 As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor((8 - 7 + 1) * Rnd())) + 7
        Dim randomValue5 As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor((10 - 9 + 1) * Rnd())) + 9
        Dim randomValue6 As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor((10 - 1 + 1) * Rnd())) + 1
        If randomValue6 = randomValue1 Or randomValue6 = randomValue2 Or randomValue6 = randomValue3 Or randomValue6 = randomValue4 Or randomValue6 = randomValue5 Then
            randomValue6 = CInt(Math.Floor((10 - 1 + 1) * Rnd())) + 1
        End If

        wb.Navigate(New Uri("http://direct.notaurl.org/games/index.php?sub=29&id=11393&ticket=" & randomValue6))
        Do Until wb.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
        wb.Navigate(New Uri("http://direct.notaurl.org/games/index.php?sub=57"))
        Do Until wb.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop

        webstring = wb.DocumentText.ToString()
        webarray = Split(webstring, ";")
        item_id = webarray(0)

        wb.Navigate("http://notaurl.org/games/index.php?sub=32&id=" & item_id & "&ticket=" & randomValue1)
        Do Until wb.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
        wb.Navigate("http://notaurl.org/games/index.php?sub=32&id=" & item_id & "&ticket=" & randomValue2)
        Do Until wb.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
        wb.Navigate("http://notaurl.org/games/index.php?sub=32&id=" & item_id & "&ticket=" & randomValue3)
        Do Until wb.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
        wb.Navigate("http://notaurl.org/games/index.php?sub=32&id=" & item_id & "&ticket=" & randomValue4)
        Do Until wb.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
        wb.Navigate("http://notaurl.org/games/index.php?sub=32&id=" & item_id & "&ticket=" & randomValue5)
        Do Until wb.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

Whenever it hits application.doevents() it returns to the beginning of the sub, why is it doing this? How do I fix it?

The first_time variable starts as true, so the first if statement gets ran. I have this code in other parts of my program and also had it in a sub of its own, and it only happens in this place, why is it doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your timer tick event is working. you have to enable it after it ticks the first time.

in the first line of your code add :`timer1.enabled=false`

Comment: But I need that to loop every second

Comment: so dont do events. or make a thread for each timer tick. the second option im not sure how but thats the way